# Get parents objects using field of Child model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have 3 models named A, B, and C. C have foreign key to B and B have Foreign key to A. What I want to do is that I want to get all the objects of class A which are related to class B andwhere objects of B are related to objects of C  using a field lookup of class C .

```
Class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to make a django query where to get all the related objects of class A which are related to class B and where B is related to Class C.

Means using value of c.name I want to get all the objects of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A.objects.filter(b__c__name='some name')
```

Comment: It gives me this error `FieldError: Relation fields do not support nested lookups`

Comment: Did you define `related_name=...` on some field? If so, you could get this error.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Thanks. I had related_name defined that's why it was giving error. Thanks

Comment: You can use `<related_name_for_b>__<related_name_for_c>__name`.

Comment: Is anyone getting that B object is not iterable?